# Restrict admin user permissions per field in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, products, permissions, acl, admin-user

Is it possible to restrict an admin user on a field basis? For example I would like some users to edit stock of a product and the short description however I don't want them to be able to change fields like the product name and sku

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a fully functional way of doing this, but I might have an idea.
If you take a look at the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes` class, the one that renders the attribute tabs on the products add/edit page, you will see this in the `_prepareForm` method

```
       if (Mage::registry('product')->hasLockedAttributes()) {
            foreach (Mage::registry('product')->getLockedAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $element = $form->getElement($attribute);
                if ($element) {
                    $element->setReadonly(true, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

This means that if the method `getLockedAttributes` from the product model, returns an array with attribute codes, they will be readonly in the form.  This gives you the client side validation.

The same `getLockedAttributes` is used to check if you are allowed to set values for certain attributes for products and categories in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::setData`.  This gives you the server side validation.

This means that you can create an observer on the product model's load method `catalog_product_load_after` where you retrieve (from somewhere...I don't know yet where from) the list of restricted attribute codes put them in an array called `$locked` then set them on the product model.
Something like this:

```
public function catalogProductLoadAfter($observer) 
{
    $locked = Magic happens here and you get from somewhere the list of attributes that the current user is not allowed to modify.
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    foreach ($locked as $code) {
        $product->lockAttribute($code);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

now the "magic" part.
My idea would be to have a separate admin section where for each admin you can dictate if an attribute can be edited by that certain admin.
Then retrieve for the current admin the list of allowed attributes.

Comment: I have built a complete module on this model. if anyone is interested, I'd be happy to share. It works on roles. This includes, read-only, hidden, hidden groups for creating and editing products alike.

Comment: @AnthonyCicchelli Hi There, Can you share your code?

Comment: @AnthonyCicchelli Are you willing to share how did you that?